# Manipulating structure of object array

Tags: javascript

I have an object array with duplicate key / value pairs. In this instance, each system has multiple sources. I would like to manipulate it's structure and add `system.Title` as an object for a single source so that each source has multiple systems.

How can I do this with `.map()` or `.reduce()`?

I have supplied the input and desired output below.

```js
//INPUT
var doctypes = [{
  "Source": [{
    "Title": "Anchor (WI)"
  }, {
    "Title": "Lafayette Savings Bank"
  }, {
    "Title": "United Bancorp"
  }, {
    "Title": "Old National"
  }],
  "System": {
    "Title": "Nautilus"
  },
  "Title": "Deposit Documents",
}, {
  "Source": [{
    "Title": "Founders"
  }],
  "System": {
    "Title": "SharePoint"
  },
  "Title": "Deposit Documents",
}, {
  "Source": [{
    "Title": "Anchor (MN)"
  }],
  "System": {
    "Title": "OmniView"
  },
  "Title": "Deposit Documents",
}, {
  "Source": [{
    "Title": "Old National"
  }, {
    "Title": "Anchor (WI)"
  }, {
    "Title": "Lafayette Savings Bank"
  }, {
    "Title": "United Bancorp"
  }],
  "System": {
    "Title": "CSS (Aperio)"
  },
  "Title": "Deposit Documents",
}]


// DESIRED OUTPUT
var doctypes = [{
  Source: 'Anchor (MN)',
  System: [{
    Title: 'OmniView'
  }]
}, {
  Source: 'Anchor (WI)',
  System: [{
    Title: 'CSS (Aperio)'
  }, {
    Title: 'Nautilus'
  }]
}, {
  Source: 'Founders',
  System: [{
    Title: 'SharePoint'
  }]
}, {
  Source: 'Lafayette Savings Bank',
  System: [{
    Title: 'CSS (Aperio)'
  }, {
    Title: 'Nautilus'
  }]
}, {
  Source: 'Old National',
  System: [{
    Title: 'CSS (Aperio)'
  }, {
    Title: 'Nautilus'
  }]
}, {
  Source: 'United Bancorp',
  System: [{
    Title: 'CSS (Aperio)'
  }, {
    Title: 'Nautilus'
  }]
}]

console.log(doctypes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to re-index the array from `System` to `Source`. I like to use dictionaries, or objects, or hash maps to pivot from on index to another. There are many other approaches to this, but I looped through `doctypes` and created a new object with the `Source.Title` and the keys and added any `Systems` I found while looping to that key'd object. Then converted the object back into an array. See code below.

```js
//INPUT
var doctypes = [{
  "Source": [{
    "Title": "Anchor (WI)"
  }, {
    "Title": "Lafayette Savings Bank"
  }, {
    "Title": "United Bancorp"
  }, {
    "Title": "Old National"
  }],
  "System": {
    "Title": "Nautilus"
  },
  "Title": "Deposit Documents",
}, {
  "Source": [{
    "Title": "Founders"
  }],
  "System": {
    "Title": "SharePoint"
  },
  "Title": "Deposit Documents",
}, {
  "Source": [{
    "Title": "Anchor (MN)"
  }],
  "System": {
    "Title": "OmniView"
  },
  "Title": "Deposit Documents",
}, {
  "Source": [{
    "Title": "Old National"
  }, {
    "Title": "Anchor (WI)"
  }, {
    "Title": "Lafayette Savings Bank"
  }, {
    "Title": "United Bancorp"
  }],
  "System": {
    "Title": "CSS (Aperio)"
  },
  "Title": "Deposit Documents",
}];

var source_dict = [];
doctypes.forEach((dc)=>{
 dc.Source.forEach((src)=>{
   if(!source_dict.hasOwnProperty(src.Title)){
     source_dict[src.Title] = {
       Source:src.Title,
       System:[]
      }
    }
    source_dict[src.Title].System.push({Title:dc.System.Title});
  })
})
console.log(source_dict);
var doctypes_out = [];
for(var o in source_dict){
  doctypes_out.push(source_dict[o]);
}
console.log(doctypes_out);
```